# Find values of a column in one dataframe in another dataframe and if not found enter zeros for entire row

Tags: r

I have 3 data frames. I want to:

1. Check if every cell value of a column is available in the counter part column of the other 2 data frames.
2. If the values are not found, it should add a row with that cell value and enter 0 for all other cells in the row.

I thought if creating a for loop for each of the values in data frame 1, but not sure how to check it with each value in the other data frames.

[image: expecteddataframesimage]

Comment: Can you please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: Please check the image I've attached, "expecteddataframesimage". Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you neeed a full_join `full_join(df1, df2, by = "col1")` and similarly for seond data and change the `NA` elements to `0` with `replace`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the image, we can do a `full_join` and then `coalesce` the '.x', '.y' columns to create a single column

```
f1 <- function(dat1, dat2, colNm) {
          dplyr::full_join(dat1, dat2, by = colNm) %>%
              dplyr::mutate(newCol = coalesce(col2.y, col2.x)) %>%
              dplyr::select(colNm, newCol)

     }


f1(df1, df2)
f1(df1, df3)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = letters[1:5], col2 = seq(10, 50, by = 10))
df2 <- data.frame(col1 = letters[c(1, 3, 4)], col2 = c(100, 150, 160))
df3 <- data.frame(col1 = letters[c(2, 5, 3)], col2 = c(200, 250, 400))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution.

First the data sets.

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = letters[1:5], col2 = seq(10, 50, by = 10))
df2 <- data.frame(col1 = letters[c(1, 3, 4)], col2 = c(100, 150, 160))
df3 <- data.frame(col1 = letters[c(2, 5, 3)], col2 = c(200, 250, 400))
```

Now a function `fun` that does what is asked in the question.

```
fun <- function(x, y){
  i <- match(y[[1]], x[[1]])
  x <- x[-i, ]
  x[[2]] <- 0
  rbind(y, x)
}

fun(df1, df2)
fun(df1, df3)
```